# Problems connecting to Interbase on remote server using php

Tags: php, interbase

Trying to set up a database connection between a Linux/Ubuntu server (client) and a Windows server (host) using the code below, but it fails for some reason. The ip address is ok (pinged it ok), port 3050 is open and username and password are also correct, so what can be the problem? The code below returns "Connection failed!!!". And yes, the php/interbase library is installed.

```
$db_path = '192.*.*.*:C:\folder\DBFILE.IB';
$username = 'USER';
$password = 'password';

$dbh = ibase_connect($db_path, $username, $password) or die('Connection failed!!!');
```

Just an update. It turned out that the connection is ok, and the problem has to do with the username and/or password. The following error is returned by `ibase_errmsg()`
"*Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.*" However, the username and password has be triple checked several times over and should be ok.

Comment: obviously the ip is masked in the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while trying to connect to interbase XE7(V12) using php ibase_connect.My interbase server was hosted in a windows 10 machine.

Make sure the php/interbase library is installed and listed in result of `get_loaded_extensions()`.

For my case the problem was in the interbase password digest. For older interbase it uses 'des-crypt' digest and for newer version it uses 'sha-1' digest. I just changed the password digest to 'des-crypt' then it worked.
  Here is the steps to change the password digest for interbase using isql.exe .

Find the admib.ib in here `C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Embarcadero\InterBase\gds_db` or under c:\program files then follow the instructions

```
1. SQL> CONNECT "C:\Program Files (x86)\borland\interbase\admin.ib" (hit enter)
2.CON> user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';

3.SQL> ALTER DATABASE SET PASSWORD DIGEST 'DES-CRYPT';

4.SQL> UPDATE USERS SET PASSWORD_DIGEST = 'DES-CRYPT' WHERE USER_NAME='sitesync';

5.SQL> COMMIT;
```

Then open gsec.exe and type these command

```
 gsec -user sysdba -password masterkey (hit enter)
 modify sitesync -pw newpassword (hit enter and password changed)
```

Back to sha-1 again

```
6. SQL> ALTER DATABASE SET PASSWORD DIGEST 'SHA-1';
7 commit;
```

And that's it. Please be noted I worked for the first time with php and interbase. Please pardon me for any missing details or typos.

Answer (score 0):

Could it possibly be that the backslashes need to be escaped into C:\\folder\\DBFILE.IB and that otherwise the C:\folder\DBFILE.IB is translated to garbage path, which IBASE doesn't find and gives the rather imprecise error msg?